# Display a canvas in a webview

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, android-studio, webview

I made a javascript project which allow to plot functions. And i want to integrate it in a webview. My problem is that only the canvas is not displayed.

Here is my activity code and my js and html   file

`public class Graphe extends FragmentActivity {

```
@InjectView( R.id.webview)
 WebView webview;

public class WebAppInterface {
    private Context context;

    public WebAppInterface(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String loadData() {
     return new Gson().toJson(context);
    }


}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_graphe);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    final WebSettings ws = webview.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    ws.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    ws.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    ws.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Plotter/site.html");
}


public void onBackPressed (){
    Intent back= new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(back);

};
```

```js
var can = $("#can")[0];
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
var STAGE = {
 WIDTH: 800,
 HEIGHT: 500
};
var fPoints = [];
var fdPoints = [];
var data = = JSON.parse(Android.loadData());;
var cursor = {x: 0, y: 0};
var VIEW = {
 X: -20,
 Y: -12,
 WIDTH: 40,
 HEIGHT: 25
};
var LQ = 3000;
var vp;
var flags = {};

var f = function(x){
 return 1/x + 4/x;
}

function translate(x, y){
 y = (VIEW.HEIGHT - y + VIEW.Y) * STAGE.HEIGHT / VIEW.HEIGHT;
 x = (x - VIEW.X) * STAGE.WIDTH / VIEW.WIDTH;

 return {
  x: x,
  y: y
 };
}

function translateBack(x, y){
 y = -1 * y * VIEW.HEIGHT / STAGE.HEIGHT - VIEW.HEIGHT - VIEW.Y;
 x = x * VIEW.WIDTH / STAGE.WIDTH + VIEW.X;

 return {
  x: x,
  y: y
 };
}


function calculate(callback){
 fPoints = [];
 fdPoints = [];
 var lastX = null;
 var lastY = null;
 var lastm = null;
 var upperBorder = VIEW.WIDTH + VIEW.X;
 var add = VIEW.WIDTH / LQ;

 for (var x = VIEW.X - (VIEW.WIDTH / STAGE.WIDTH * 10); x < upperBorder; x += add) {
  var y = 0;
  var innerX = x;
  try{
   y = callback.call(this, innerX);
  }
  catch(ex){
   y = 0;
  }

  //--> only draw new line when "m" is different
  if(lastX !== null && lastY !== null){
   if(lastm !== null){
    var curm = (y-lastY) / (innerX - lastX);
    if(curm === lastm){
     var _tmp = fPoints[fPoints.length - 1];
     _tmp.x = innerX;
     _tmp.y = y;
    }
    else{
     fPoints.push({x: innerX, y: y});
    }

    fdPoints.push({x: innerX, y: lastm});
    lastm = curm;
   }
   else{
    lastm = (y-lastY) / (innerX - lastX);
    fPoints.push({x: innerX, y: y});
   }
  }
  else{
   fPoints.push({x: innerX, y: y});
  }
  
  lastX = innerX;
  lastY = y;
 };

 //console.log("added " + (fPoints.length - 1) + " lines.");
}

function calculateArea(callback, x){
 var s = x * VIEW.WIDTH / STAGE.WIDTH / 50;
 var field = 0;
 var m = x < 0 ? -1 : 1;

 for (var i = s * m; Math.abs(i) < Math.abs(x); i += s * m) {
  field += s * callback(i);
 };

 return field;
}

function calculateTangens(callback, x){
 var x1 = x - VIEW.WIDTH / 1000;
 var x2 = x + VIEW.WIDTH / 1000;

 var y1 = callback(x1);
 var y2 = callback(x2);

 var m = (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2);

 return {
  m: m,
  b: y1 - m * x1
 };
}

function parseInfix(){
 var postfix = new Postfix($("#infix").val());
 var callback = postfix.generateCallback(postfix);
 f = callback;
 calculate(f);
}

/* * * * * * * * * * * Initialize * * * * * * * * * * */

function init(){
 can.width = STAGE.WIDTH;
 can.height = STAGE.HEIGHT;

 can.style.width = STAGE.WIDTH + "px";
 can.style.height = STAGE.HEIGHT + "px";

 ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
 ctx.shadowColor = "black";
 ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';

 $("#infix").val("e^x");

 //check url
 if(document.URL.indexOf("#") !== -1){
  var splitted = document.URL.split("#");
  if(splitted[1].trim().length !== 0){
   $("#infix").val(splitted[1].trim());
  }
 }

 parseInfix();

 //Input flags
 var leftPressed = false; // false, or xy object
 var newVIEW = {
  X: VIEW.X,
  Y: VIEW.Y,
  WIDTH: VIEW.WIDTH,
  HEIGHT: VIEW.HEIGHT
 };

 //Animation rendering
 var animationRender = function(){
  var zoomSpeed = 30;

  VIEW.X += (newVIEW.X - VIEW.X) / 100 * zoomSpeed;
  VIEW.Y += (newVIEW.Y - VIEW.Y) / 100 * zoomSpeed;
  VIEW.WIDTH += (newVIEW.WIDTH - VIEW.WIDTH) / 100 * zoomSpeed;
  VIEW.HEIGHT += (newVIEW.HEIGHT - VIEW.HEIGHT) / 100 * zoomSpeed;

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animationRender);
 };

 window.requestAnimationFrame(animationRender);

 //Flag check loop
 var flagCheckLoop = function(){
  if(flags.btnToOrigin === true){
   $("body").css("cursor", "pointer");
  }
  else{
   $("body").css("cursor", "default");
  }

  window.setTimeout(flagCheckLoop, 50);
 };
 window.setTimeout(flagCheckLoop, 50);

 //recalculate every n seconds
 var calculateLoop = function(){
  calculate(f);

  window.setTimeout(calculateLoop, 500);
 };
 window.setTimeout(calculateLoop, 500);

 $(can).mousemove(function(e){
  cursor.x = (e.offsetX || e.clientX - $(e.target).offset().left);
  cursor.y = (e.offsetY || e.clientY - $(e.target).offset().top);

  if(leftPressed !== false){
   var moveX = VIEW.WIDTH / STAGE.WIDTH * (leftPressed.x - cursor.x);
   var moveY = VIEW.HEIGHT / STAGE.HEIGHT * (leftPressed.y - cursor.y);

   newVIEW.X += moveX;
   newVIEW.Y -= moveY;
   leftPressed = {x: cursor.x, y: cursor.y};

   
  }
 })
 .mousedown(function(e){
  cursor.x = (e.offsetX || e.clientX - $(e.target).offset().left);
  cursor.y = (e.offsetY || e.clientY - $(e.target).offset().top);
  leftPressed = {x: cursor.x, y: cursor.y};

  if(flags.btnToOrigin === true){
   newVIEW.X = -VIEW.WIDTH / 2;
   newVIEW.Y = -VIEW.HEIGHT / 2;
  }
 })
 .mousewheel(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var zx = VIEW.WIDTH / 10;
  var zy = VIEW.HEIGHT / 10;

  newVIEW.X += zx * (cursor.x / STAGE.WIDTH) * e.deltaY;
  newVIEW.WIDTH -= zx * e.deltaY;

  newVIEW.Y -= zy * (cursor.y / STAGE.HEIGHT) * e.deltaY;
  newVIEW.HEIGHT += zy * e.deltaY;

  calculate(f);

  return false;
 });

 $(document).mouseup(function(e){
  cursor.x = (e.offsetX || e.clientX - $(e.target).offset().left);
  cursor.y = (e.offsetY || e.clientY - $(e.target).offset().top);
  leftPressed = false;

  calculate(f);
 });

 $("#do").click(function(){
  parseInfix();
 });

 $("#infix").keyup(function(){
  window.location.hash = $("#infix").val();
 });
}

init();


/* * * * * * * * * * * Render * * * * * * * * * * */

function render(){
 window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

 can.width = can.width;
 var xcoord = translate(0,0);
 vp = translateBack(cursor.x, cursor.y);
 var tan = calculateTangens(f, vp.x);

 //draw axis
 ctx.beginPath();
 //X
 ctx.moveTo(0,translate(0, 0).y);
 ctx.lineTo(STAGE.WIDTH,translate(0, 0).y);
 //Y
 ctx.moveTo(translate(0, 0).x, 0);
 ctx.lineTo(translate(0, 0).x, STAGE.HEIGHT);
 ctx.lineWidth = 1;
 ctx.stroke();


 //cursor field to y
 ctx.beginPath();
 var s = vp.x < 0 ? -1 : 1;
 s *= VIEW.WIDTH / STAGE.WIDTH * 3;
 for (var i = 0; Math.abs(i) < Math.abs(vp.x); i += s) {
  var vx = translate(i, f(i));
  ctx.moveTo(vx.x, xcoord.y);
  ctx.lineTo(vx.x, vx.y);
 };

 ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
 ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(150,150,200,0.5)";
 ctx.stroke();


 //Cursor
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(cursor.x, 0);
 ctx.lineTo(cursor.x, STAGE.HEIGHT);
 ctx.moveTo(0, cursor.y);
 ctx.lineTo(STAGE.WIDTH, cursor.y);

 ctx.lineWidth = 1;
 ctx.setLineDash([2]);
 ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
 ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(150,150,255)";
 ctx.stroke();


 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(cursor.x, xcoord.y);
 ctx.lineTo(cursor.x, translate(0,f(vp.x)).y);
 ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(100,100,255)";
 ctx.lineWidth = 2;
 ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
 ctx.setLineDash([])
 ctx.stroke();



 //plot
 if(fPoints.length > 0){
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0, l = fPoints.length; i < l; i++) {
   var p = translate(fPoints[i].x,fPoints[i].y);
   
   if(p.y >= -10000 && p.y <= 10000){
    if(i===0)
     ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
    else
     ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
   }
  };
  
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
  ctx.shadowColor = "black";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.stroke();
 }


 

 
 //Draw data
 data.fy = f(vp.x);
 data.fx = vp.x;
 //data.Fx = calculateArea(f, vp.x);
 data.tm = tan.m;
 data.tb = tan.b;

 
 //draw icons -->
 //
 var opacity = 0.5;
 var size = 30;
 var cursorIn1 = 
  cursor.x >= STAGE.WIDTH - 10 - size && cursor.x <= STAGE.WIDTH - 10 &&
  cursor.y >= 10 && cursor.y <= 10 + size;

 if(cursorIn1){
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,255, 0.8)";
  flags.btnToOrigin = true;
 }
 else{
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,255, 0.5)";
  flags.btnToOrigin = false;
 }

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(STAGE.WIDTH - size / 2 - 10, 10);
 ctx.lineTo(STAGE.WIDTH - size / 2 - 10, 10 + size);

 ctx.moveTo(STAGE.WIDTH - size - 10, size/2 + 10);
 ctx.lineTo(STAGE.WIDTH - 10, size/2 + 10);
 ctx.stroke();

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(
  STAGE.WIDTH - size / 2 - 10, 
  size/2 + 10,
  size / 4,
  0,
  2*Math.PI);
 ctx.arc(
  STAGE.WIDTH - size / 2 - 10, 
  size/2 + 10,
  size / 8,
  0,
  2*Math.PI);
 ctx.stroke();
}

render();


/* * * * * * * * * * * Data - Render * * * * * * * * * * */

function niceRound(num, digits){

 var p = Math.pow(10, digits);
 var s = "" + (Math.round(num * p) / p);
 if(s.indexOf(".") === -1){
  return num;
 }

 var cpart = s.split(".")[1].length;

 for(var i=0;i<digits - cpart;i++){
  s += "0";
 }

 return s;
}

function dataRender(){
 var round = 3;

 $(".fx").text(niceRound(data.fx, round));
 $(".fy").text(niceRound(data.fy, round));
 $(".Fy").text(niceRound(data.Fx, round));
 $(".tm").text(niceRound(data.tm, round));
 $(".tb").text(niceRound(data.tb, round));

 window.setTimeout(dataRender, 100);
}

dataRender();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>plot</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="plot,2D,function,f(x)" />
 <meta name="description" content="Plots a function" />
 <meta name="viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1, minimum-scale = 1, maximum-scale = 1, user-scalable = no" />

</head>
<body>
 <div -webkit-class="canvas-holder">
  <form action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="infix-box">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <input class="input-formula" type="text" placeholder="infix" id="infix" />
     </td>
     <td -webkit-style="width: 120px;text-align: right;">
      <input -webkit-id="do" type="submit" value="Plot" />
     </td>
    </tr>
    
   </table>
  </form>
  
  

  <canvas id="can"> </canvas>

  <div -webkit-id="dataBox">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <th>
      f(<span class="fx"></span>)
     </th>
     <td>
      <span class="fy"></span>
     </td>
    </tr>
    
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 


 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="postfix.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $("#short").click(function(){
  var postfix = new Postfix($("#infix").val());
  $("#postfix").val(postfix.postfix.join(" "));
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

some help please !!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/Plotter/site.html", "", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

instead

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Plotter/site.html");
```